# Как изменять внешний вид ссылок?

Tags: css, ссылки

Есть это

```
<a href="#" id="a1">1</a>
```

И

```
<a href="#" id="a2">2</a>
```

Как надо написать в CSS чтобы сделать допустим для первой ссылки в обычном состоянии чтобы не было подчёркивающей линии и цвет был чёрный. А для второй в обычном виде всё стандартно, но при наведении на неё курсора допустим она становилась зелёной?

Comment: `<a class="link1" href="#" id="a1">1</a>` а для ссылки 2 класс 2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#a1 {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
}

#a2:hover {
    color: green;
}
```